# How to change current languague of the system with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code to change the current language of the system:

```
CultureInfo TypeOfLanguage = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = TypeOfLanguage;
InputLanguage lang = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage);
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
```

The code ran well for window form project, but it could NOT change the current system language for MVC application.

I tried to reach more solution for MVC project but no luck so far. Can anybody help me on this?
How can I make the system language change for MVC project?

I would appreciate for your help.

---

@IyaTaisho : you may misunderstand what I mean. I don't wanna change language on the website. I wanna change language of the system. I did more and more searching on google as well as stackoverflow before posting the question here.

As I mentioned before, the code could run well on window form, but could NOT run on MVC application. This is what I want to reach.

For example:

- I have dropdown on my web page contains 2 language option: English and Chinese.
- when I select English then I can type the English with my keyboard. But when I select the Chinese then I can type Chinese anywhere on my website, as the language of the system has been change after selecting the language option from the dropdown.

Can you or anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: windows forms have a lot fewer restrictions.  MVC is a web site and web sites can't (and shouldn't) change system settings

Answer (score 0):

You can change what language you are using in your web.config file.  Here is an example of one: [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1318941.aspx?How%20to%20Set%20default%20language%20in%20web%20config%20file%20).  Also, a simple Google search returns plenty of examples on how to change the language.